# Flexdashboard shows blank tab meant for mobile-only view

Tags: r, mobile, shinyapps, flexdashboard

I have a flexdashboard that uses a tabular display. I want one version of a tab to display in desktop view, and another in mobile view. When I use the {.mobile} specification, it displays a duplicate of the non-mobile tab in desktop view, except with blank contents.

Example code:

```
---
title: "MY DASHBOARD"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
   theme: 
     version: 5
     bootswatch: cosmo

     
runtime: shiny
---

Charts {.tabset}
-------------------------------------

### Chart 1

{r}
head(airquality)

### Chart 2

{r}
head(mtcars, n = 3)

### Chart 2 {.mobile}

{r}
head(iris, n = 3)
```

What it looks like in desktop:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Answered my own question. It seems that this feature of flexdasboard only works if you individually set the non-mobile tabs to be {.no-mobile}, and then recreate the mobile-friendly tabs under a new tabset that is globally {.mobile}

```
---
title: "MY DASHBOARD"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
   theme: 
     version: 5
     bootswatch: cosmo

     
runtime: shiny
---

Charts {.tabset}
-------------------------------------

### Chart 1 {.no-mobile}

{r}
head(airquality)



### Chart 2 {.no-mobile}

{r}
head(mtcars, n = 3)




Charts {.tabset .mobile}
-------------------------------------

### Chart 1

{r}
head(airquality)



### Chart 2

{r}
head(iris, n = 3)
```